# How can I tell VS2010 to include files in my manifest for publishing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, manifest

I have an application that is published through the ClickOne mecanism. The issue I'm having is that it is not publishing my `NLog.config` file, which is required for my application to run. I've looked through the `Application Files` screen, but I don't see `NLog.config` as an option to select. My `NLog.config` file has a built action of `Content` and is set to copy to the output directory. If it matters the `NLog.config` file is in another project that is referenced in the project I'm publishing.

I'm aware that I can use MAGE to essentially scan my publishdirectory and have it update my manifest, but what I'm looking for is a way to do it automatically.

What are my options?

#### Possible Solution

One solution could be to configure NLog through code rather than XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this great tool too and I have a click-once program too:
In the Solution explorer, click on your nlog.config. In the properties window, put the Build Action as content.

Be sure that you see "Applications files" of the project's properties window.

Voilà!

Comment: My configuration file is set as `Content`. I'm not sure what you mean by your second statement regarding `Application Files`.

Comment: I meaned: Go on the project's properties page. Click on the "Publish" tab. Click on "Application files", you should see "Nlog.config" somewhere. If not, click on "Show all files".

Comment: Ah, it's not there even if I click `Show all files`. Would it matter if my configuration file is in another project? I have in a `Common` project so I can use it in several places.

Comment: About this particular point, I have no clue. BUT I know that if your nlog.config is in your main project directory, it will be included in your output.

Comment: What I ended up doing was keeping `NLog.config` in my `Common` project and adding it as a link. Thank you. :)